# Display Text with HTML image tag inside WPF control

Tags: html, .net, wpf, image, richtextbox

I try to display a Text that contains a string plus HTML tags, and render images.

```
SourceText="TextToDisplay <img Source="Http://...cat.png"> and thats <b>it</b>";
```

RichTextBox doesnt work well.

I found some NuGet packages:

- HtmlRenderer : But cannot access image that needs my Windows credentials to access, no way to send credential, so i got error 404 for images.
- HtmlAgilityPack : Does not work for images
- HtmlRichTextBoxBehavior : Does not work for images

I'm out of ressources....

Use case is I try to replicate TFS Description box in a WorkItem, it can contains HTML tags.

When i query TFS api to get Description, thats what we receives and i want to display the same box with the same iamges....

Comment: Have you tried the [WebBrowser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.webbrowser?view=netframework-4.7.2) control? It's _NavigateToString(string)_ method let's you render any text/ html content.

Comment: As an alternative approach you could consider to parse the result string and extract the required elements to display them with WPF controls.

Answer (score 0):

It's WPF, so you can just build whatever custom control you want very easily.

Start with a `TextBlock` and an `Image` control inside a `StackPanel` and go from there.  It doesn't have to be any more complicated than that if you don't want it to.  Or you can add a bunch of extra functionality if you need extra features.  WPF gives you the flexibility to build whatever you want.

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="TextToDisplay"/>
    <Image Source="http://myUrl.../myImage.png"/>
</StackPanel>
```

This places them one after the other.  If you want them to overlay one another, use a `Grid` to hold them.  If you want a MouseOver effect, use a `PopUp` control.  If you want an actual hyperlink in the UI, use the WPF `Hyperlink` element.

Comment: Text came from a bug description from tfs / visual studio, it can contains anything i dont know in advance